# Is it possible to Redo commits removed by GitHub Desktop's Undo on a Mac?

Tags: git, github, version-control

The "[GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)" Mac app has an "Undo" button in the commit area of the main view.

[image: GitHub Desktop for Mac Screenshot]

Clicking it appears to remove the most recent commit from the repository without asking for confirmation. While local changes are still available, undoing past anything that's not currently in local appears to completely erase it from the repository history. Here's the log of a demonstration repository. After a few commits and before pressing "Undo", it looks like this:

> - f6e4436 (master) Initial commit.
> - a3857ad Added example file.
> - cf17c3b Added critical content.
> - 35f1c76 (HEAD -> dev) Accidentally delete critical line.

The critical line is no longer in local or the last commit at this point. It is still available via the "cf17c3b" hash.

Clicking undo once produces this:

> - f6e4436 (master) Initial commit.
> - a3857ad Added example file.
> - cf17c3b (HEAD -> dev) Added critical content.

After two:

> - f6e4436 (master) Initial commit.
> - a3857ad (HEAD -> dev) Added example file.

And finally a third press of the "Undo" button brings the state of the repo back to this:

> - f6e4436 (HEAD -> dev, master) Initial commit.

After the last two "Undo" clicks, the "cf17c3b" commit is no longer accessible (i.e. the critical line I accidentally erased seems to have been completely removed).

I'm not seeing anything in the app to "Redo" the changes done by "Undo". That's very surprising since the button doesn't require a confirmation that it's potentially going to permanently delete code. My questions are:

1. **Is it possible to "Redo" from inside the app to restore the commits removed by "Undo"?**
2. **Is it possible via the command line if it's not possible via the app?**

Comment: When I tried this the files in the commits I undid became untracked and I can see them in the working dir. In your case, did the files get deleted?

Comment: The file is still there. However, the line I need isn't there because of commit (35f1c76). (e.g. it maintained it's state, but that state does not contain the line I needed or anything else that was removed in the later commit.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know about via the app, but using `git reflog` you can find the history of where `HEAD` has been, then merge the current branch with that commit to recover it (and all previous commits). My guess is that the app uses `git reset` to undo the commit, so your reflog might look like this:

```
0ba8580 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to head~
1451518 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to head~
79b5909 HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to head~
a28c206 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from 4de17de8c1a89f17db894150144e58f8b0b50f6c to master
4de17de HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to head~4
a28c206 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from 5005e7d017b15cf6d725ca01ac586e566338fa86 to master
```

The most recent action is first on the list. What you want to do is merge with the line *after* the `reset` you want to undo. So for example in this case, you could try `git merge HEAD@{3}`. If you want to examine the commit before merging with it, do `git show HEAD@{3}`.

Comment: I ran the command. It only returned one line/commit. (I updated the question to add this info as well.) If I'm properly understanding what `git reflog` does, I think that means the app really did completely removed my content from version control.

Comment: Hmmm, that is really odd. Is `35f1c76` the actual SHA of the commit you have lost? If so, you should be able to merge it in anyway with `git merge 35f1c76`.

Comment: I also tested this with the app and I can confirm that the undo function seems to work as described by @daviddeutsch.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry that the code is gone. I found the sha with the critical line still intact in the .git/objects dir. git show <sha> shows the code. So it is still there, question is how to get it back in as it seems to be disconnected somehow.

Comment: @AlanW.Smith - did you do the `git reflog` on the same machine where you did the undo?

Comment: Just reran the experiment and `git reflog` worked this time. I'm assuming I did something weird when I was going back and forth to make the SO question succinct. Either that or doing Undo past a branch change threw it off. Anyway, this appears to work. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: I ended up doing `git reset HEAD@{3}` Instead of `git merge HEAD@{3}`. Keeping this as the accepted answer but we might want to add that note.

Comment: @AlanW.Smith, that would be equivalent as long as `HEAD{3}`  is strictly ahead of `HEAD` (and you use the `--hard` option), since it would be a fast forward merge. In any event, glad it worked out for you!

Comment: You save me from Dead